# browsing WAMP localhost shows blank page

Tags: apache, configuration, installation, wampserver

After downloading and installing WAMP, I visit http://localhost in Firefox. It's showing a blank page. Here are some factors:

1. No Skype
2. Windows Vista Home Basic SP2
3. Firewall is off
4. Deleted the `::1 localhost` in `c/windows/system32/drivers/etc/host`
5. Tried changing port to `8080` in httpd.conf

When I go to Apache/services/test 80 it shows:

```
your port 80 is actually used by..........
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: do you have another web server running on your computer, perhaps IIS? If so you'll need to either shut it down or set the Default Website to listen on a different port.

Comment: Run `netstat -o` from command line to see what application is using port 80.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the warp icon in your dock can you 'put online'.

Comment: yup,,,by the way IIS is using port 80 and i've tried to change the port for apache in httpd.conf to listen 8080 but still its not working what shall i do now

Comment: how to analysis netstat -o,actually im not good at cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, here is the solution !

**Cause :**

Another program (Skype but not only) is using the port80 (which is by default the one used by wamp).
You can see it typing the following command "netstat -ano" and looking what is on "localadress 0.0.0.0.80", if you want to see the concerned program open, note the number at the end of the line (4 for example), then open taskmanager, services, and see who is on PID 4.

**Solution :**

Let's **change wamp port to 81** !

[Change wamp port from 80 to 81](http://xfloyd.net/blog/?p=515)